# How to vertically align a div with absolute position on top of each other?

Tags: jquery, css, html, position, z-index

I have two divs, that I need to be places right on top of each other, inside another div. Simple, I use z-index and give them position:absolute. But the contents of each of these divs needs to be vertically aligned. When I position them on top, they do not center vertically.

Is there a way to mix both of these styles to do this?

Or is this possible with jQuery somehow?

This is basically what I have.

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="height:400; width:400; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; z-index:0; position:absolute;"><img></div>
  <div style="height:400; width:400; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; z-index:1; position:absolute;"><img></div>
</div>
```

I have height and width, table-cell and vertical-align as middle. This centers the content until I add the absolute position which I need for the z-index to work.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you have something against `position:relative`?

Comment: the images will be 400x400  or variable sizes?

Comment: The images will always be a variable size, depending on what is loaded from the user.
But the two images must overlap each other, and more often than not, they will be a bit smaller inside the view area (the div they are contained in, that is a set size)

Comment: Can you make a demo showing the problem? Use for example  http://jsfiddle.net/ and http://www.dummyimage.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra-div inside the second one: http://jsfiddle.net/MDJDx/

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="height:400px; width:400px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; z-index:0; position:relative;top:0;">img</div>
  <div style="height:400px; width:400px; z-index:1; position:absolute; top:0">
    <div style="height:400px; width:400px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; position:relative;">img</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best option, and seems to be the only way to make it work with inline <svg> graphics. `line-height` works with an image tag, but not svg. Creating a second div splits up the index layering, and aligning so it works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

give your inner divs `line-height:400px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/2DXPg/1/

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm wanting.
It looks like 'vertical-align, text-align, and line-height' are all needed on the <img> tag as well for this to work? My images will be inline <svg> and it doesn't appear to work on those. Maybe that's my issue..
Thanks for this though! I'll get it to work somehow with this example. I've never even seen this jsfiddle.net but like it :)

Comment: For some reason this does not seem to work with inline <svg> elements the same as an <img> :/

Answer (score 1):

Style the two inner divs with

```
position: relative; top: 0px;
```

in addition to what you already have

Comment: The two divs are then stacked, one under another rather than on top :/

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought that's what you had intended.  Sorry!  So do you want them literally overlapping each other?  One completely covering the other?

Comment: Yes, they're actually svg files with lots of transparency, which is being used to create an effect

Comment: I would go with David Nguyen's solution in that case, it seems to work for what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
margin: auto;
```

to the div with the content you would like to center. For this to work you MUST set a width on this div too.

Maybe

```
width: 100%;
```

should do the trick.